# Dbcc checkident syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

Hi I have tried to reseed my table using dbcc checkident(table,reseed,100)
And I havent mentioned table name in quotes will this cause any issues although it ran successfully

Comment: Have you checked..?

Comment: Very confusing on what you are asking here. It ran successfully? And? Did you try with `NORESEED` first to see what the maximum value would be?